# Is there any way to change screenshot buttons in phones which don't have it in the settings?

Tags: photos, buttons

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core GT-I8262.

Its power button has some issues and I can't take screenshots using the combination of power and home buttons (I can't take screenshots using the combination of other keys).

It doesn't have the screenshot feature in the notification bar. Also, there isn't anything regarding screenshots in settings.

So is there a way to change the buttons to, for example, home and volume-down keys?

Comment: If your device is rooted, yes. If not, maybe an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irishin.buttonsremapper) may help

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks. How can I find out if it's rooted or not?

Comment: If you are the first owner and didn't root it, then it is not //many root checker apps are available on play store. They can help